# Ubuntu wont boot (only blank screen) after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

Upgrade Manager suggested an upgrade of my Ubuntu to 14.04. All seemed to go well, but after restart, Ubuntu fails to boot. Only a black screen appears, and I don't know what to do. I can't even access grub (the shift key is ignored, only the word "GRUB" appears on screen, ctrl+alt+f1 doesn't work either). I need to preserve data on the HDD.

Comment: Were you using proprietary driver? Maybe this can be the cause fo your trouble.
Anyway, use a live ISO to backup your data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, too, so I downloaded and burned the Ubuntu 14.04 on DVD and booted from it. I selected "install Ubuntu" and the option which installs Ubuntu without formatting or losing data. It does ask for a default user - just use the same user than before, so it will be mapped to the original home directory.

I had to re-install all my applications, but as the configuration files were not erased, a lot of things reverted to as they were before.

The other users were manually and I had to do some "chown" to ensure that they matched the old one, as the owner of the home directory user1 was user2, etc...

I am sure that there is other method, but as you mentioned, I wanted to get back on my feet very fast.  It took me 30 minutes to get a working computer.  I am sure that I have missed some applications but when I will need them I will re-install them.